# Partition guides and possible solutions?

Tags: mysql, partitioning

We have a table called tblLink which is the main table and have its primary key in many other tables as shown below. The issue now we want to keep only the latest 3 months data and the rest should be delete and archive. The one option to partition each individual tables separately based on dates. Is there any option or solution where based on the linkID in tblLink I do the partition together for the rest of the tables? Is partitioning the right way to move or is there any other options?

All these are InnoDB tables.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblLink` ( 
`linkID` int(5) NOT NULL, 
-- other columns
PRIMARY KEY (`linkID`) 
); 


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblEmailLog` ( 
`emailLogID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`linkID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
-- other columns
PRIMARY KEY (`emailLogID`) 
); 


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblEventAlert` ( 
`eventAlertID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`linkID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
-- other columns
PRIMARY KEY (`eventAlertID`) 
); 



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblMainData` ( 
`mainDataID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`linkID` int(5) NOT NULL, 
-- other columns
PRIMARY KEY (`mainDataID`)
); 


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblSubData` ( 
`subDataID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`mainDataID` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`linkID` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`eventAlertID` int(11) NOT NULL, 
-- other columns
PRIMARY KEY (`subDataID`) 
);
```